# Чтение из файла и поиск

Tags: python

У меня есть файл, в котором куча строк, в каждой строке куча слов и чисел разделенных запятой. Мне нужно организовать поиск построчно, по определенному слову в строке...

Я сделал так:

```
def search(obj1, obj2): 
while True:
    line = file_airport.readline() 
    if obj1 in line and obj2 in line: 
        kel = ''.join(line) 
        L = kel.split(',')
        print ('Airport code {0} \n{1}\n{2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7}\n{8} {9}\n'.format \
               (L[:1], \
                L[-2:-1], \
                L[8:10], L[10:11], L[7:8], L[5:6], L[3:4], L[2:3], \
                L[-4:-3], L[-3:-2]))
    if not line:
        break
file_airport.seek(0)
```

Но это он ищет просто на совпадения (широта и долгота); думаю, можно сделать это через вложенные словари или списки, но получается у каждой строки должно быть 2 ключа? Не понимаю, как реализовать это...(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если строки в файле типизированы, я бы сделал разбор по шаблону с группировкой в кортеж. А там искать уже проще. Пример:

```
import re
myPattern = re.compile(r'''
                    # начальные символы игнорируются
(...нужный шаблон...)           
\D*                 # любой разделитель
(...нужный шаблон...)
\D*                 # любой разделитель
...
$                   # конец строки
''', re.VERBOSE)

try:
    return myPattern.search(string_from_file).groups()
except AttributeError:
    return 'Error in line: %s' % string_from_file
```

Так будут корректно обрабатываться пустые параметры (две подряд запятые) и игнорироваться все строки не подходящие под нужный формат.

P.S. Почему не подходят простые методы работы со строками?

```
>>> s='ABE,AIRPORT,USA,18109,,PA,,Allentown,,3311,Airport Rd,-75.43424,40.6514,Lehigh Valley International Airport,'
>>> 'USA' in s
True
>>> s.find('USA')
12
```

Comment: Ну..в моем примере я работаю не со строкой, а со списком..)
А идея с шаблонами заинтересовала, а можно поподробней, что значит нужный шаблон?(синтаксис и логика) =)

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Для регистронезависимого поиска нужно и строку, и ключ перевести или в lowercase, или в uppercase и дальше просто делать in.

Comment: obj1 и obj2 тоже должны быть lowercase. если это не гарантируется, то лучше и для них это сделать:
if obj1.lower() in line and obj2.lower() in line:

Comment: Если использовать словари, то ключ будет tuple(широта, долгота). Можно использовать named tuple, они есть стандартной библиотеке. 
Файл тогда тоже должен хранить словарь. Читаете весь файл в словарь, делаете в нем поиск по ключу.

Comment: Хм...пробовал так D = dict.fromkeys(tuple(L[-4:-3], L[-3:-2]), L))...по разному пробовал, не выходит(
А что значит файл должен хранить словарь?я не могу его изменять...
Извиняюсь за свою неграматность в языке..(

Comment: В каком виде у Вас данные лежат в файле? Пример приведите.

Comment: ABE,AIRPORT,USA,18109,,PA,,Allentown,,3311,Airport Rd,-75.43424,40.6514,Lehigh Valley International Airport,

это одна строка..
где 2 запятых - пустой параметр получается...

Comment: При запуске программы считываете содержимое файла в словарь.
Сначала читаете одну строку и делаете split(",") -> получите список, 8 и 9 элементы которого - ключи словаря, а остальные элементы - значение.
Пример: http://pastebin.com/uCELHgd8

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали и как там написано, выдает ошибку - 
TypeError: tuple() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)